# How can I use Django variables in my javascript/client-logic?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to serialize a queryset to use it in javascript to populate a chart.
The problem is that it don't let me serialize the object. If I remove `queryset` it works, but I need the queryset in the context to use it for Django rendering as well.

So how may I use the variables both with Django to render the html divs and javascript to render a chart? (in this case it is a canvas why I need the variables on the javascript site).

**views.py** where `currency` and `dynascore` are two custom variables and `queryset` is the Django model query

```
[...]

context = {
        'queryset': queryset,
        'currency': currency,
        'dynascore': dynascore,
    }

    # Prepare context for javascript
    json_context = json.dumps(context)
    context['json_context'] = json_context

    print(queryset)
    return render(request, template, context)


// Throws: 
// Object of type StocksPrice is not JSON serializable
```

**Javascript**

```
console.log(json_context)

// Throws: 
// Uncaught ReferenceError: json_context is not defined at terminal.js:1
```

So as far as I understood the one and only "bridge" between Django retrieved data and javascript/client-side is JSON?

Comment: have u tried `{{ json_context }} ` ?

Comment: @Sher where? for the console.log?

Comment: yes, if data is not showing properly, try `console.log({% autoescape off %}
      {{ json_context }}
      {% endautoescape %})`

Comment: You can try to use it within the script tag as Sher say. <script>var data='{{json_context}}' ... {/script}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another view and get the data to your javascript with ajax by the url /chartdata.

views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def chartdata(request):
    ...
    context = {
        'queryset': queryset,
        'currency': currency,
        'dynascore': dynascore,
    }
    return JsonResponse(context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('chartdata', views.chartdata,  name='chartdata'),
]
```